# Have you got to re buy destiny and its DLC?

Tags: destiny

I was thinking about getting an Xbox One, but would like to know if I get it, would I need to buy Destiny and its DLC to play it on the Xbox one?

Comment: Did you buy it digitally on XBox 360?

Comment: No I have the disc

Comment: From what I've read, you can only upgrade for free if you bought the digital edition.  I could be wrong so I'm not putting it as an answer, but I believe you will have to buy it again if you want to play it on XBox One.

Comment: @TheUnicornMaster Please stop proposing minor suggested edits.  Unless you can provide a substatial improvement to a post, you don't need to make additional irrelevant edits to hit the character limit for suggested edits.

Comment: Upgrading a physical copy can only be done through a game store. Even then, your not upgrading, your trading in your old copy. The trade in values are often low, especially for anything that isnt current gen. Im pretty sure characters automatically move across, if that helps at all.

Comment: @Frank I am not trying to just meet the character limit. I try to edit all grammar issues I can find. I think this helps the readability of posts. I will try to improve my edits from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

While digital upgrades are sometimes made available, you must have the digital version of the game on Xbox 360. Having the physical disc unfortunetly won't cut it.

You might see the option of simply using your old version, through backward compatability, but this has a couple of drawbacks.
 - This title is unlikely to be released, due to how accessible it already is on Xbox One
 - If you do get away with backward compatibility, you will only be able to play with Xbox 360 players
 - You will still not technically own any of these games on Xbox One.

It might simply be worth considering trading your old copy in for a legendary edition of Taken King on Xbox One. While you will likely only receive a small amount of credit for your older version, this would be the most cost effective way to obtain the game on the newer console. This assumes you do not play Destiny with your friends, as you will need to play it on Xbox 360 to play with friends who are also on an Xbox 360/ playing an Xbox 360 version.